# Recording Microphone with Cubase problem

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, cubase, steinberg

I am new to sound recording.
I have a [Steinberg UR22 MKII](https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/audio_interfaces/ur_series/models/ur22mkii.html) sound card that I have connected to mono inputs (one for my electric piano and one for my dynamic microphone).
The microphone input only records anything if the Input gain knob is set to maximum! Even then the voice gets recorded only if it is higher than a threshold.

I am using an XLR cable for the mic.

The cubase project has 2 audio tracks which are assigned to the UR22 as mono inputs.

The Vocal track only has Cubase's "default" vocal effects, i.e. the ones which are added as part of its sample "piano and vocal" project.

Comment: I assume you mean a UR22 MKII?  What microphone is it?  What input is it connected to?  How is it connected?  XLR cable?  How is the Cubase track set-up?

Comment: What mic are you using?  I've never used this template before as I always work from scratch, but I've just taken a look at it and it seems fairly straightforward.  The send are not the problem as it's just sending signal to the reverb FX track.  Look at your "VST Connection" in Cubase and check what Mono 2 is connected to the correct input on your interface.  Open up the mixer and check the level for Mono 2, by default it should be at 0dB.  Also try swapping your inputs on the UR22 over to ensure that both are working.  Remember to change your VST connections though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Input #1 for the mic, or if you are using Input #2 make sure to disable the "Input 2 Hi-Z" button (See attached picture).

That button is a sort of impedance control which allows for plugging in instrument level devices (like a guitar) and performance will be poor when a microphone is connected to that input with that setting enabled.

[image: Interface front plate with indicator for impedance switch]

Comment: Thank you so much @DoritoStyle ! even with a disabled "Hi-z" i experience the same problem. but changing the mic to the first line definitely had positive effect. where have you gotten the picture?

Comment: I pulled the image from here: https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/audio_interfaces/ur_series/models/ur22mkii.html